# Restricting access to resources by source and destination IP

Tags: design, networking, system

Forgive me if this is the wrong place to ask such questions - I am still extremely new to this field and am not even sure where the most appropriate place to look for answers is.

**Question:**

Assume I have a system in 2 physical locations: A and B. A and B are connected via a site-to-site VPN.

There are two groups of nodes in A.The two groups of nodes can be distinguished by their IP addresses: they have different ip addresses with no overlap between the two groups. Both groups of nodes in A are trying to access resources in B.

B's resources are spread across nodes with different internal IP addresses. Let's look at a particular subnet of 192.168.1.X in B, for instance.

My goal is to allow node group 1 and node group 2 in A to only access specific resources in the subnet. For example, Node Group 1 can only access 192.168.1.1-192.168.1.200, and Node group 2 can only access 192.168.1.201-192.168.1.255. If Node Group 1 tries to send a call to 192.168.1.255, it should throw an error/not be allowed to.

The two main constraints are:

1. Any solution has to be implemented on A and A only - we cannot implement a black/whitelist on B. As far as B is concerned, all requests from A come from the same group.
2. The assignment has to be relatively easy to change. For example, the solution should allow us to change Node Group 1 to have access up to to 192.168.1.233 and restrict Node Group 2's access to only 192.168.1.234-192.168.1.255

Does anyone have any ideas on how this could be achieved? My initial thoughts involve some configuration on the firewall of the site-to-site vpn, or programming an intermediate module that checks for authorization on all calls before forwarding requests to B, but even if these are correct, I'm not sure what resources to search up next to learn how to implement them.

Thank you, and apologies again if I posted this to the wrong place.

Comment: you could do this with a firewall or software router in front of your servers, but its not a great idea. divide your network up properly, add a second VPN or something more secure

Comment: Thank you for your reply! To clarify, do you mean something like:

1. Set up 2 site-to-site VPNs from Server A to Server B |

2. Cleanly separate the networks for User Group 1 and User Group 2 in Server A |  

3. Let the network for User group 1 route through the first VPN, and the network for User group 2 route through the second  |

4. Configure each VPN (or the firewall associated with each?) to allow traffic only to the appropriate resources in B?

Comment: pff, i hadnt thought it through in detail, basically split A into A1 and A2 setup firewall, router, vpn, physical networking accordingly so that traffic from A1/2 **MUST** traverse the firewalls/routers containing the rules you want to enforce. vs hide B servers behind a software firewall/router and point traffic to that, hoping that no-one finds a work around

Comment: Much appreciated. I will try that and see how it goes!